# From a security point of view is it ok to send an instagram user access token and userid to a client in a JSON object?

Tags: instagram-api

Is it a problem that I store instagram userid and token in my database and then send it in a json object to members of the public. The instagram user who uploaded their credentials of course knows that this is occuring, and can disconnect their instagram profiles at any time.

Is this a problem?

I am using instafeed for this

```
  initStagram(id, token){
    var feed = new Instafeed({
      get: 'user',
      userId: id,
      accessToken: token,
      resolution:"standard_resolution",
      template: '<a target="_blank" href="{{link}}"><img class="isstyle img-rounded" src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}}"/></a>'
    });
    feed.run();
  }
```

Comment: who get the `access_token`? is it just the user who authenticated ?

Comment: No, the token is sent to the client side of public visitors to the site. Although as mentioned it is not logged or shown in the site, it is just used from there to make calls to the instagram api

Comment: so any public user will be using some random user's `access_token` to make API calls ?

Comment: The api call is made once, when the public user comes to the site. Thats it, so the public user is not controlling the api calls. Its not random either, its for the specific instagram user who decided to upload their instagram user credentials for that purpose.

Comment: which API call are u making ?

Comment: I am using instafeed... I am updating my comment to show the code. But basically it just displays the images as if you were to go to www.instagram.com/username... And then the images for username that show up there.

Comment: ok, i understand now, client requesting user and u sending `access_token` to client and client making API call, why dont you instead make API call on server and send response to client, this does not involve sending out `access_token` to client

Comment: ahah...Okayy...that sounds like it should work....But, I am really not sure how to do that, I will look at that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending JSON object with `access_token`, you can just use the `access_token` received in hash fragment after user completes Instagram login, and save it in app. This way `access_token` is only received by client only after actual user logs in.

I'm guessing you have your own API to get JSON object with `access_token`, then anyone will be able to make that call and get anyone's `access_token`?

The secure way to do it is to have instagram send the `access_token` to client using the `redirect_uri`. Also when the user logs out in app, you should delete the saved `access_token`

Comment: I reformulated my question, I feel like it was maybe slightly confusing before, and while I appreciate your time to answer the question, I felt like your answer did not answer my question...Which was my fault because I dont think I phrased it properly. Check it now if you are still interested @krisrak